# Is there a way to include a ACF field in the permalink for a custom post type in WordPress?

Tags: wordpress, permalinks

Right now, I have a custom post type called `books` and when creating new posts, WordPress generates my permalinks based off the CPT name and the post title, like this:

```
/books/the-south-was-right
/books/lost-in-a-good-game
/books/surrounded-by-idiots
/books/do-hard-things
/books/chop-wood-carry-water
```

Each of my posts also using a ACF field called ISBN, so I would like to have my permalinks display something like:

```
/books/1396321853/the-south-was-right
/books/1785786148/lost-in-a-good-game
/books/1250179939/surrounded-by-idiots
/books/006309861X/do-hard-things
/books/1483441784/chop-wood-carry-water
```

This does not look to be a built-in option of ACF and I have searched their support forums and found some mix results around the correct way of doing this.

Without adding another plugin to the my site, how can I set these permalinks up for all future posts and then also rewrite the permalinks for all my previous posts?